# How to write or open a php array without evaluating or expanding magic constant __DIR__

Tags: php, string, magic-constants

I have a config file that is a php array named config.php.

```
return array(
    'template_dir' => __DIR__ '/configs/templates.php'
)
```

Then whenever I want to use this config file I would just include config.php.  Its also really easy to write a config file in this way.

```
file_put_contents($config, 'return ' . var_export($data, true));
```

But I would like to be able to write the magic constant **DIR** to the config file without it expanding.  So far I have not been able to come up with a way to do this.  I have tried everything to writing a recursiveArrayReplace method to remove the entire path and trying to replace it with

```
    __DIR__
```

but it always comes up as

```
    '__DIR__ . /configs/template.php'
```

Which in that case will not expand when its ran.

How can I write

```
   __DIR__ to an array in a file or how ever else without the quotes so that it looks like,

array('template_dir' => __DIR__ . '/configs/templates.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because `var_export()` prints variables, not expressions.

It would be better to write all your paths as relative directories instead and canonicalize to a full working path after fetching the data.

You could also consider returning an object:

```
class Config
{
    private $paths = array(
        'image_path' => '/configs/template.php',
    );

    public function __get($key)
    {
        return __DIR__ . $this->paths[$key];
    }
}

return new Config;
```

Alternatively, you'd have to generate the PHP code yourself.

Comment: You are right this is not possible in the end.  I have tried every possible way to output the magic constant without being expanded.  I ended up resorting to $buffer = fgets($handle) and doing a str_replace over the buffer and then writing it back to the file.  It works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the path with `__DIR__`, you need to replace the starting apostrophe as well.

E.g. if the path were `/foo/bar` then you'd want to do this replacement:

`"'/foo/bar"` to `"__DIR__ . '"`

---

Before:

```
'/foo/bar/configs/template.php'
```

After:

```
__DIR__ . '/configs/template.php'
```

Comment: I had tried this hoping that was the solution, but it still wraps everything in quotes.

Comment: You would need to do this after the `var_export` step, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

What about write the config directly by:

```
$data = <<<EOT
return  array('template_dir' => __DIR__ . '/configs/templates.php');
EOT;

file_put_contents($config, $data);
```

Comment: This idea actually works, I would just need to figure out how to use this since I build my arrays dynamically.  But you are right it doesn't expand the constant.